# Optimization of second order ODE with more than one parameter

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I want to optimize a second order ODE  with more than one variable:

```
Exp[2*alpha*x]*D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + (2*alpha + a)*Exp[2*alpha*x]*
D[theta[x], x] - b^2*(theta[x] - thetaa) - c*(theta[x] - thetaa)^2 + d*Exp[2*alpha*x] == 0;
```

With boundary conditions

```
theta[1] == 1, theta'[0] == 0.20
```

Here `a, b, c, d,thetaa` are parameters and `alpha=-0.5`. I want to maximize `theta[x]` for different parameters
I have no idea how to do it please help me

Comment: `C` and `D` are built-in symbols and should not be used as parameters. In general, all user-defined symbols should begin with a lower case letter to avoid naming conflicts with built-in symbols. If `{a, b, c, d}` are the parameters, what are the values for the constants `{alpha, thetaa}`?

Comment: @Bob Hanlon thanks for the correction, here 'thetaa' is also a parameter and alpha=-0.5

Comment: Recommend placing an NDSolve of the DE in a Manipulate with sliders for all constants and studying how the solution varies as the constants are varied.

Comment: In what sense do you wish to maximize `theta[x]`?  Also, are the parameters all real?  Are there bounds on the values of the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the constraints provide in the OP's comment below, `theta[x]`, maximized over `{x, a, b, c, d, thetaa}`, can be obtained as follows.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Exp[2*alpha*x]*D[theta[x], {x, 2}] + 
    (2*alpha + a)*Exp[2*alpha*x]*D[theta[x], x] - b^2*(theta[x] - thetaa) - 
    c*(theta[x] - thetaa)^2 + d*Exp[2*alpha*x] == 0) /. alpha -> -1/2, 
    theta[1] == 1, theta'[0] == 1/5}, theta, x, {a, b, c, d, thetaa}];

NMaximize[{s[a, b, c, d, thetaa][x], 0 < x < 1, 0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1, 
    0 < c < 1, 0 < d < 1, 0 < thetaa < 1}, {x, a, b, c, d, thetaa}]
s[a, b, c, d, thetaa] /. %[[2]];
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, theta}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]

(* {1.39758, {x -> 0.226436, a -> 0.0000966814, b -> 0.00719679, 
              c -> 0.0000613951, d -> 1., thetaa -> 0.000312072}} *)
```

[image]

Incidentally, increasing `WorkingPrecision` from the default machine precision to `30` changes the maximum of `theta` by about 0.2%, and the values of the parameters at that maximum by modest amounts:

```
(* {1.39474388212895176033538369038, 
   {x -> 0.218410943433777148986614046571, a -> 0.0108420208584436753782203010895, 
    b -> 0.0153768430340760880593013278062, c -> 0.00248978147185524573445645380282, 
    d -> 0.998856326052919487344087798466, thetaa -> 0.663626080541074452717478080028}} *)
```

Note that the result is insensitive to `thetaa`, because it is multiplied in the ODE by `b` or `c`, which are small.

Comment: #bbgodfrey thanks for your effort my problem is to maximize and minimize 'theta'  where the range of values of the parameters  is '[0,1]'

Comment: @ZDN  With this additional information, the answer can be obtained with less running time, on my computer about 3 minutes.  Please see above.